# dictionary values are being overwritten when adding new key and values

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am trying to populate a dictionary with 4 keys, each key value is a multi-dimensional array (13,7). The first key and array populate perfectly. When the second key populates, the values for both the first and second keys have the second array iterations values and this continues for the next 2iterations until I have 4 keys and all the same values. I have validated line by line using a watch to verify each array has unique values and each key has a unique value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Dim BitMap As New Dictionary(Of String, String(,))
 For y = 0 To strDiffEQName.Length - 1
        For x = 0 To 1
            Dim intFirst As Integer = Array.IndexOf(rowvalue, "[" & strSTKName & "_" & strSendRecv(x) & "_" & strDiffEQName(y) & "]") 'Find first string in Array (Start Block)
            Dim intSecond As Integer = Array.LastIndexOf(rowvalue, "[" & strSTKName & "_" & strSendRecv(x) & "_" & strDiffEQName(y) & "]") 'Find second string in Array (Stop Block)
            Dim intNum As Integer = 0

            For i As Integer = intFirst + 1 To intSecond - 1 'Loop through array betwween start and stop block
                Dim strHolder() As String 'Array that will temporary hold values until transfered to the strString Array
                strHolder = rowvalue(i).Split(","c) 'load data between commas to the temporary array
                ReDim Preserve strHolder(strHolder.Length - 1) 'Increase rows in array by one
                For k As Integer = 0 To 7
                    strString(intNum, k) = strHolder(k) 'Load temp data into multi-dimensional array
                Next
                intNum = intNum + 1 'Increment to next row in Multi-dimensional array
            Next
            BitMap.Add(strSendRecv(x) & "_" & strDiffEQName(y), strString) 'Transfer Multi-dimensional array to Dictionary
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: arrays are reference types.  adding the array to the Dictionary for iteration 1 doesnt make a copy of the data, it saves a reference to the data.  So in the next iteration when you put new data in the array (change it) you are also changing the data in the Dictionary because they are the same array.  You probably just need to create a new array for each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I stepped through each iteration and found that as soon as anything changed in the array, that value also changed in the dictionary just as you said. With that being said, I guess I need to know what will work to import my array into the dictionary with values instead of references. Should I iterate through each element in the array with a .tostring() adding each to the dictionary?

Comment: `System.Array` has a `.CopyTo` function, you should be able to use it to copy the contents to a NEW array variable to be stored.  better yet, try to devise a class which you can create for each iteration (arrays are vile).  hard to advise without knowing what the data represents, it looks like chars parsed from a string.

Comment: Thanks again for your information. It seems the way I was going about this was futile. Since the amount of arrays needed is unknown until runtime, I instead created a structure with a name and array. At runtime I declare the structure as an array with the number of elements needed. At this point the dictionary is redundant, so I simply run through the structure array iterations until I find the correct name and use the corresponding array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said, arrays are reference types.  That can't be changed.  If you want to add four items to the `Dictionary` then you have to create four arrays.  It's that simple.  If you just create one array and add that four times then obviously you'll only see one set of data regardless of the item in the `Dictionary` you look at.

Consider this.  Let's say that you are taking a list of people's names and the colour of the shirt they are wearing.  I step up wearing a red shirt and you take down my details.  I then step up again wearing a blue shirt and you take done my details again.  If you then call my name from the first item, would you expect me to be magically wearing a red shirt again, even though I took it off and put on a blue shirt?  I'm only one person, no matter how many times you put my name on the list, so you're going to see the last colour shirt I put on, no matter what list item you use to select me.  That's how objects work in the real world and that's how objects work in programming.